# UserAgentUtils always giving null browser version

Tags: java, user-agent, kettle

I'm using the UserAgentUtils Java library to extract user agent details from the user agent string of browsers during a PDI transform, but no matter what I do I always get back a null version from the library after parsing the user agent string, even when I can clearly see the version in the string.  For example:

```
String userAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) capybara-webkit Safari/533.3"
UserAgent userAgent = new UserAgent(userAgentString)
userAgent.getBrowserVersion() //always comes back null
```

Two questions.  What am I not doing right to get back the data from UserAgentUtils (it doesn't seem to be a bug because there's no history of issues related to this in their bug tracking system)?

Alternatively, is there another Java or JavaScript library I could use to extract the component information from user agent strings?  Either one is okay, since I can equally easily use either in the PDI job where this code lives.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: this was from a long time ago, but I'm pretty sure i ended up using a combination of a regex and another library i found listing user agent strings online (no, i don't remember which one or have a link, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to set the http agent value for jetty http client requests?

i do this on my user defined java class:

```
import java.lang.System.*;
...
System.setProperty("http.agent", "my cool crawler, mycoolcrawler@example.com");
```

now all your http requests from kettle will send user agent header with this info

Comment: Nope, I actually need to extract the data from http server logs but don't need to set it for requests.